# How could I hack conditional behaviour into django-survey?

Tags: django, survey

I need a survey application very soon. django-survey seems to be nearly what I am looking for. But one feature is missing: conditional questions

i.e.:

> have you been taking part in this....
>
> yes no
>
> if your answer is yes, please proceed
>   with Question 1.1. if it is no, please
>   proceed with Question 1.2

Here it should be checked, that

> if yes -> 1.1 is answered and 1.2 not
>
> if no -> 1.2 is answered and 1.1 not

Do you know a way to implement a conditional-check hack for django-survey?

Comment: Isn't this open source?  Why would you have to hack anything?

Comment: I dont mean hacking as cracking. I mean extending the functionality quick'n'dirty with some hacks, that should never find their way to some deliverable software.

Comment: Your question seems to be talking about deliverable software though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to publically release another open source Django Questionnaire/Survey application shortly, which has support for complex dependencies/conditionals.  I will place the source on github at http://github.com/rmt/.  It will most likely be called Seantis Questionnaire.  It is being used for an online medical questionnaire Seantis GmbH is working on.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of conditionals are not too many, you should use JQuery to hide and unhide the respective questions.

If there are too many conditionals spanning across multiple screens, you may use the [Dynamic Forms](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2008/10/dynamic-forms-with-django/)